# Problems with esp8266 '/' in website links

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have been using the Sparkfunesp8266 library to ping websites. However what I noticed is website with '/' are not recognized or identified by the library. Example if I say `esp8266.ping("google.ca")` vs `esp8266.ping("google.ca/")` there is a problem. What can be done?

Comment: You need to try using an esp8266 shield. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You always ping a *host* rather than a domain name or so. '/' is not a valid character in a host name - just omit it.

Comment: You should use the ra8875 library to solve this problem.